# Combining two simple SQL Server queries takes long running time

Tags: sql-server, ogc

I have two simple queries that execute within expected time when they run alone.
The first query:

```
SELECT OBJECTID AS OID FROM PST_35053_SNAPPED;
```

Takes less than a second and returns about 3000 rows.
The second query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PST.OBJECTID as OID FROM PST_35053_SNAPPED 
PST INNER JOIN  POWNERS_35053 POW
ON geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + convert(varchar(16),POW.x) + ' ' +
convert(varchar(17),POW.y) + ')', 2100).STWithin(PST.Shape)=1;
```

Takes a second returning about 2500 rows.

When combining them with `EXCEPT` to retrieve `polygon IDs` without points falling in them (about 500 rows), the resulting query takes more than two minutes to execute (about 122 seconds):

```
SELECT OBJECTID AS OID FROM PST_35053_SNAPPED
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT PST.OBJECTID as OID FROM PST_35053_SNAPPED 
PST INNER JOIN  POWNERS_35053 POW
ON geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + convert(varchar(16),POW.x) + ' ' +
convert(varchar(17),POW.y) + ')', 2100).STWithin(PST.Shape)=1
```

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong?
I am using **SQL Server 2012 SP3**

Comment: How much faster is it without the distinct (which isn't needed)? Also, have you tried exists instead?

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/

Comment: DISTINCT does not affect duration. I also tried NOT IN and NOT EXISTS with the same long running result

Comment: THen please post the execution plan :)

Comment: [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkrmoIhT7)
@EricZ

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert your script to temp table than combine it. We don't have execution plan we can only show you to execute your query with different angles. :

```
SELECT DISTINCT PST.OBJECTID as OID INTO #Temp FROM PST_35053_SNAPPED 
PST INNER JOIN  POWNERS_35053 POW
ON geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + convert(varchar(16),POW.x) + ' ' +
convert(varchar(17),POW.y) + ')', 2100).STWithin(PST.Shape)=1;

SELECT OBJECTID AS OID FROM PST_35053_SNAPPED
EXCEPT
SELECT OID FROM #Temp;
```

or try not exists :

```
SELECT OBJECTID AS OID 
FROM PST_35053_SNAPPED PST1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT PST.OBJECTID as OID FROM PST_35053_SNAPPED 
            PST INNER JOIN  POWNERS_35053 POW
            ON geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + convert(varchar(16),POW.x) + ' ' +
            convert(varchar(17),POW.y) + ')', 2100).STWithin(PST.Shape)=1
        ) PST2
        WHERE PST1.OBJECTID=PST2.OBJECTID
    )
```

or try WITH :

```
WITH Cte AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT PST.OBJECTID as OID FROM PST_35053_SNAPPED 
    PST INNER JOIN  POWNERS_35053 POW
    ON geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + convert(varchar(16),POW.x) + ' ' +
    convert(varchar(17),POW.y) + ')', 2100).STWithin(PST.Shape)=1
)
SELECT OBJECTID AS OID FROM PST_35053_SNAPPED
EXCEPT
SELECT OID FROM Cte;
```

Comment: Thanks Zeki. This executes in 2 seconds with the desirable results, but I would like an explanation for the delay. I am using the queries in software code and I would  like to avoid temporary tables.

Comment: hi @ApostolisKotidis I checked your execution plan. I can assume only except works slowly when you use multiple join. Also,I think(can't prove) it seems spatial data works slowly with except.  I put another query with using NOT EXISTS instead of using temp table (because you don't want to use temp table). Could you check it please.

Comment: I checked it but the result is worse. It takes more than 3 minutes. I also checked NOT IN with the same results. I tried UNION and INTERSECT instead of EXCEPT too. UNION takes less than a second as expected, INTERSECT is very slow taking 1 minute and EXCEPT is terribly slow taking 2 minutes. It does not seem to be a coding problem , but an SQL Server matter. I will try to test it on another edition of SQL Server

Comment: Hi @ApostolisKotidis , I have added another solution using WITH clause.

Comment: thanks Zeki. I already have tried the CTE version but it is as slow as the other approaches. I also ran the query on an SQL Server 2014 SP3 and got the same slow behaviour. I cannot figure this out..

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without query execution plan.
However, if I understand correctly, the following query should get the same result, and would be faster.

```
SELECT PST.OBJECTID as OID 
FROM PST_35053_SNAPPED PST 
LEFT JOIN  POWNERS_35053 POW
ON geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + convert(varchar(16),POW.x) + ' ' +
convert(varchar(17),POW.y) + ')', 2100).STWithin(PST.Shape)=1
WHERE POW.OBJECTID IS NULL
```

Comment: why would it be faster?

Comment: No, it took 193 seconds to run. I also tried variations with NOT EXISTS and NOT IN with nested selections and took also more than 2 minutes time.

Comment: please share execution plan